# camel file component how to send entire folder

Tags: apache-camel

I have the following folder hierarchy :

- D

  - D1

    - D1doc1.txt
    - D1doc2.otherext
    - Readme.txt
  - D2

    - D2doc1.txt
    - othertext.txt

Using Camel file component, I would like to send the repertory D1 and its content to another endpoint. So far I manage to send file independently or a whole content of a repertory, but I don't know how to send with the prvious structure the repertory D1 and its content (not just the content)

To send all the content of D1, i am writing :

```
from("file://D/D1/?noop=true&recursive=true").to(.....)
```

and it sends everything inside D1 correctly. Now to send D1 as a full directory with the contents, I tried :

```
from("file://D/?fileName=D1&noop=true&recursive=true").to(.....)
```

of course not working as camel file is apparently designed to work for file only and not directories like I saw on this link :

http://grokbase.com/t/camel/users/1485bjq5zr/polling-a-directory-for-inner-directories

However, it looks annoying and strange to me as I have to make a hack changing the previous hierarchy into :

- D

  - D1

    - D1

      - D1doc1.txt
      - D1doc2.otherext
      - Readme.txt
  - D2

    - D2

      - D2doc1.txt
      - othertext.txt

so that when I use :

```
from("file://D/D1/?noop=true&recursive=true").to(.....)
```

it finally does what I want sending the directory as well.
Is there really not a cleaner way to do this ? If no, what is the reason behind ?

Comment: actually just added "&minDepth=1" and made the trick as specified in documentation...

Answer (score 2):

Use recursive to tell Camel to travel down sub directories. And you can use the min/max depth options to control from and how far you go down.

This is the **clean** solution using the correct options for what they are intended.

For example on unix the find command also has minx/max depth options and its the similar concept in the Camel file component.

More details at: http://camel.apache.org/file2

And if you do not want to build the directory structured on the 'other side' you can use the `flattern` option.

Answer (score 0):

It's a kinda old thread but I'm sure it will help someone

```
from("file:D:\\INPUTFOLDER?noop=false&recursive=true&maxDepth=NUMBEROFSUBDIR").process(new MyProcessor()).to("file:D:\\OUTPUTFOLDER");
```

> in here NUMBEROFSUBDIR.. will be +1 from the main
>   directory(INPUTFOLDER) and it won't copy the folder unless you have
>   file present in it, as it supports FTP.